# antd - How to generate scriptUrl in Custom Font Icon

Tags: reactjs, antd, icon-fonts

I want to add a [play icon](https://www.iconfont.cn/search/index?q=play) to my `antd-Button` component in (`React`), I tried to follow [antd-Icon documentation](https://ant.design/components/icon/#Custom-Font-Icon) and [Icon font help](https://www.iconfont.cn/help/detail?spm=a313x.7781069.1998910419.15&helptype=code) without success in generating `scriptUrl`

From official docs:

```
const MyIcon = Icon.createFromIconfontCN({
  scriptUrl: '//at.alicdn.com/t/font_8d5l8fzk5b87iudi.js', // generated by iconfont.cn
});

ReactDOM.render(<MyIcon type="icon-example" />, mountedNode);
```

> `scriptUrl` is The URL generated by iconfont.cn project.
>
> The property scriptUrl should be set to import the SVG sprite symbols.

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
const PlayIcon = Icon.createFromIconfontCN({
  scriptUrl: '', // How to generate url?
});

// Button inside component
<Button shape="circle" onClick={someAction}>
  <PlayIcon type="icon-play"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have your account in iconfont.cn,

- go to the `Icon & Project`
- goto "My project"
- click the "view the online link" to get it

[image]

**Side note,**

since they are dropping the support for  component in favor svg as component. you may prefer download the svg y do

```
import { Icon } from 'antd';
import PlayIconSvg from 'path/to/playIcon.svg'; // path to your '*.svg' file.

ReactDOM.render(
  <Icon component={PlayIconSvg} />,
  mountNode
);
```

Comment: In my case `import ... from '....svg'` not worked cause resulting symbol content was base-64 encoded data.  So, `<Icon component={mySvg} />` didn't work.  Many thanks for clarifying how to generate code, you've made my day.

Comment: But how do you add an icon to 'My project'??

Comment: Just hover the icon, click the shopping cart to add to cart. after you are done click the top right shopping cart icon and click "add to project"

Comment: i don't see a .js file but if you change the .svg to .js it works